# Can magic command %run accepts dynamic path in Azure Databricks?

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I am assigning notebook path of a python script with functions dynamically and then trying to use this path under %run magic function. It fails with "Notebook not found error".

But if this path is provided as a direct string it executes without error.

[image]

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Include it dynamically, or executed based on some condition?

Comment: I'm interested in this and basically want to pass the path of a config file to my script.  I followed the example %run {path} from https://forums.databricks.com/questions/2866/does-run-support-using-a-variable-to-specify-the-n.html but get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay on the answer... I guess you did already solved it, but as a suggestion, i might use the function instead:

```
dbutils.notebook.run(path)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).